# Moverse en tablero con teclas direccionales

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un laberinto en C++ con un tablero cargado desde un archivo, y no sé cómo moverme con las flechas del teclado. Dejo el código de la función `CargarLaberinto()`, que muestra el laberinto desde un archivo, y la función `Juego()`.

**CargarLaberinto()**

```
void CargarLaberinto();
{
  ifstream nomArchivo;
  string tablero;
  nomArchivo.open("Tablero.docx", ios::in);

  while(!nomArchivo.eof())
  {
     getline(nomArchivo, tablero);
     cout << tablero << endl;
  }
}
```

**Juego()**

```
void Juego(int filas, int columnas)
{
  bool GANASTE = false;
  bool Perdiste = false;
  int tecla;

  do
  {
     CargarLaberinto();

     switch((tecla = getch()))
     {
    case ABJ:

       break;

   case ARR:

    break;

   case IZQ:

    break;

   case DER:

    break;
    }

}while(!GANASTE && !Perdiste);

if(Perdiste)
{
    cout << "Perdiste :(" << endl;
}

if(GANASTE)
{
    cout << "Has encontrado la salida!! GANASTE!!!" << endl;
}
```

Hice un `#define` para cada flecha y que, cuando el usuario las pulse, pueda moverse por el laberinto hasta la salida (y gana). Si en el recorrido choca contra un muro, pierde y empieza de nuevo. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Como moverme en un tablero cargado desde un archivo con las flechas

Comment: No lo entiendo ¿Cargado con las flechas? ¿Moverse con las flechas? No veo que estés haciendo nada en el `switch` de `void juego(int, int)`.

Comment: El tablero se carga desde un archivo. Cuando se muestra por pantalla, que el usuario se mueva con las flechas del teclado desde el inicio hasta el final.

Comment: Con un switch case debería de ser suficiente.

Comment: No sé qué valores le diste a los defines de cada flecha, pero Tecla arriba es 72, abajo es 80, izquierda es 75, y derecha es 77.

Comment: Sí, esos valores usé para los defines de las flechas

Answer (score 0):

ES: creo que es ambiguo para la PC, no estas escribiendo lo que las flechas deben hacer, ejemplo: si indicas que la flecha es derecha, debería hacer algo (mover dibujo posición x+=1) pero el switch esta vació, dice si la techa es abj, der, izq, arr "break"... tenes que definir que significan esos movimientos, el programa no va a divinar que significa, solo sabe que las teclas están definidas.

Comment: Hola Alejandro, bienvenido a la comunidad, te comento que aquí respondemos en español el cual es el idioma oficial del sitio por lo que no hace falta redactar también en inglés

Comment: jaja ok gracias por avisar, es que tengo puesto el traductor de chrome para las páginas en ingles y a veces me olvido si estoy en una página en español.

Comment: El switch es para que el jugador se mueva por el tablero en la dirección dependiendo de la tecla direccional que el usuario presionó, pero no sé como implementar eso. Por eso el switch está vacío.